# Logical vector with multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have te following dataframe:

```
a    b     c     d     e
TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I would like to create an extra column , say f, with the following logic:

```
TRUE = If all the columns in the corresponding row are all TRUE or all FALSE.
FALSE = if one or more colums differ from the other columns in the corresponding row.
```

In this example the output would be

```
a    b     c     d     e     f
TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I like the clever answers, but this is crying out for use of an `xor` function!

Comment: @beroe - I'm struggling to see how you would easily adapt `xor` to this circumstance, but I'm willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: @thelatemail - Just wondering about it. As you know, for two objects, XOR is true if they are different and false if they are the same, so that seems to me to be the exact inverse of what the OP wants for column `f`. In R, you can `!(xor(df[,1],df[,2:5]))` and if any of those are false, then the corresponding value in `f` would be false. I just don't know a by-row version of `min()` or `any()` to apply next. So maybe not easy, but just came to mind as the most "logical" operator to use.

Answer (score 11):

Use this:

```
DF$f <- apply(DF, 1, function(x)(all(x) || all(!x)))
```

where "DF" is your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! Very cool @Ferdinand.kraft! Would you explain a bit more how does this one-liner work please?

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, exploiting the fact that `logical` values are just `0`s and `1`s for arithmetic:

```
rowMeans(dat) %in% 0:1
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by @Ferdinand.kraft is correct, and is the most readable answer, but a hack is to use `rowSums`:

```
DF$f <- rowSums(DF) %in% c(0, 5)
```

This is about 33% faster on my system:

```
> system.time(replicate(10000, apply(DF, 1, function(x) {all(x) || all(!x)})))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.11    0.00    3.12 

> system.time(replicate(10000, rowSums(DF) %in% c(0, 5)))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.95    0.00    1.95
```

But, as I said, this is something of a hack and should probably only be used when speed is important.

Comment: As in my answer, `rowMeans` may be more suitable as it doesn't require having to specify the possibly variable sum value.

Comment: I voted both this one and @thelatemail but I'll point out why I prefer `rowSums` here to `rowMeans`. Here `rowSums` will return an integer vector while `rowMeans` will return a numeric one. As you know numeric comparisons are always subject to floating point errors: while it may not have a real impact here, it is in my opinion good practice to use integers when you can. Of course that requires you compare with `c(0L, 5L)` or more generally `c(0L, ncol(DF))` here, not `c(0, 5)`. The `L` is important to get an integer vector.

Answer (score 3):

As far as speed goes, this is pretty fast:

```
do.call(pmin.int,dat)==do.call(pmax.int,dat)
```

Speed test:

```
microbenchmark(
    allorall=apply(dat, 1, function(x) {all(x) || all(!x)}),
    rmeans=rowMeans(dat) %in% 0:1,
    rsum=rowSums(dat) %in% c(0, 5),
    minmax=do.call(pmin.int,dat)==do.call(pmax.int,dat)
)

Unit: microseconds
     expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 allorall 278.598 287.7760 301.8145 340.9585  722.410   100
   rmeans 178.174 182.4925 191.6715 205.9790  471.888   100
     rsum 177.093 182.7625 188.4315 202.4695 1796.304   100
   minmax  17.278  19.9775  22.1375  26.1870   42.115   100
```

Why isn't there a `prange`?