# Removing row with duplicated values in all columns of a data frame (R)

Tags: r

With the following data frame:

```
d <- structure(list(n = c(2, 3, 5), s = c(2, 8, 3),t = c(2, 18, 30)), .Names = c("n", "s","t"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like:

```
> d
  n s  t
1 2 2  2
2 3 8 18
3 5 3 30
```

How can I remove row with duplicated values in all column. 
Yielding:

```
  n s  t
2 3 8 18
3 5 3 30
```

Comment: For this specific two column problem, `d[with(d, n != s),]` would work

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thanks but, I need to have generalize form. Cause in real case the column name could varied and more than just 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible approach, which compares all columns to the first

```
d[rowSums(d == d[,1]) != ncol(d),]
#   n s  t
# 2 3 8 18
# 3 5 3 30
```

Comment: `d[rowSums(d == d[,1]) != ncol(d),]` - borrowing from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708647/logical-vector-with-multiple-columns-in-r/18708906