# Checking for identical values across multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 15 factor columns. I need to create a new column that gives a true/false binary for whether all the values in a given row (for just those columns) are identical.

I've found this strategy...

```
identical(df[['A']],df[['B']])
```

...but that checks the entire column, whereas I need a solution by row.

Comment: Some worthwhile options here, particularly this answer from Frank - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839567/496803

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `DF` as shown in order to test it, apply `unique` to each row and for each row check whether the length of the result is 1

```
DF <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = c(1:2, 1), C = 1)
transform(DF, same = apply(DF, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1))
```

giving:

```
  A B C  same
1 1 1 1  TRUE
2 2 2 1 FALSE
3 3 1 1 FALSE
```

Alternately using dlyr 1.0 or later:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
 rowwise %>%
 mutate(same = n_distinct(unlist(cur_data())) == 1) %>%
 ungroup
```

Comment: How would I select specific columns using this method?

Comment: If ix is a vector of column numbers or column names then replace the second occurrence of DF with DF[ix].

Comment: i would be nice a pipe operator approach selecting columns with the function select() for specific columns